# Can't run Python file via Command Prompt, File is not defined error

Tags: python

I am new to Python and currently doing a basic python course to learn. I have been running code all day via the Command Prompt and it has been working fine. For some reason though it has stopped working and python files I try to run are returning the following error:

***Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined***

As per the screen shot and the numbers on it, I performed the following steps in an attempt to run the file:

1. change to the folder where file is saved
2. run 'dir' to list all files. I am trying to run 'hello.py'. This contains the code: print('hello simon!')
3. I can run the file by just typing hello.py into the command prompt, this works ok
4. I can also run with: python hello.py - this works ok
5. when I activate Python by typing Python --> Enter, this starts the interpreter ok. However if I then try to run by typing hello.py I get the error message.

This has worked ok all day, I have not changed anything on my PC (to the best of my knowledge!) but just started to get this error a few hours ago. I have looked all over the internet for solution but found nothing. I have uninstalled and re-installed Python, restarted etc... all to no avail.

I am running Python 3.6.5 on a Windows 7 64 bit PC.

It won't let me attach a picture so here is link to screenshot of Command Prompt and error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBUe5.jpg

I hope someone can help me with this please
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** supposed to execute **hello.py** in the Python Interpreter. It **won't** work. When you type in *python and hit Enter* in your Command Prompt, Just type this,

```
>>> print('hello simon!')
```

And hit Enter, it would definitely work. Because the interpreter is supposed to execute a code line by line. So if you want to run a Python Script then do not execute it in the Interpreter.

Comment: Ok, understand now, had got myself totally mixed up and ended up running round in circles! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you write python (alone), the command line calls python shell and the following commands are run inside the python shell and not in the command line anymore. Calling a script from the shell has a different format (look it up). You can enter exit() to exit the shell back to command line again

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is you are running Hello.py inside Python.
Not with Python.

You need to run Hello.py with Python. As python is interpreter over here.

```
>>>python
```

means you are going inside python shell

```
>>>print('hello simon!')
```

Is equivalent to your program.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your Python Script as you should and it's working. If you added Python to your path you can run Script you only need to call the Script "hello.py". If you have more than one intepreter, or you didn't added it to your path then you can call it like this `"C:\path\to\python\interpretet\pythonxxx.exe" "c:\path\to\python\script.py"` you can enven pass arguments to it `"C:\path\to\python\interpretet\pythonxxx.exe" "c:\path\to\python\script.py" --argument`

When you type `python` in a shell, then interactive mode is activated. This is like a shell where you type commands and got interpreted right away, in the same way as `cmd` and `powershell` works, but for python. This way you can test snippets, or just do simple stuff overly complicated like this

```
import os

ls = os.listdir(os.path.abspath('c:/'))
def print_dir():
    for file in ls:
        print(file)
```

Wich in cmd would be `dir c:\` or in powershell `ls c:\`. The point is that you can test libraries, explore objects, replace the shell or just have fun.